# Can I define two primary keys in a database table & why?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, contactbuilder

In relational databases we can only define one primary key. Is it possible to define two primary keys, probably one is primary and other is secondary key and can be joined on any of the two fields.

Comment: Is this question related to Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Comment: yes. This is related to contact builder in marketing cloud. sql is used to create data extensions.

Comment: I've added those relevant tags to the question. Generic relational database questions sometimes are closed as off-topic; it's helpful to make the context clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , we can only define one primary key but you can define unique indexes in your table which can also work like primary key in that case they should have unique values .

Comment: SFMC Users cannot create indexes on Data Extensions without some sort of engagement with Salesforce.

Comment: This answer seems misleading to me. You can define multiple primary keys that act as a single composite key, so saying you can only define a single primary key but can include unique indexes doesn't seem entirely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell a bit more about **your goal**? That might help to give you the best answer. More than one road leads to Rome after all. :-)

You could have `unique indexes` set up by Salesforce, but these may require Salesforce Services (at a fee), although you can also try to initiate a support ticket. I'm not sure if they would handle that now.

Another - perhaps easier - work around is to work with two data extensions:

1. DE1: Primary key + any other information
2. DE2: Primary key (as a look up to DE1) + your "secondary key"

Then you could write a (SQL) [Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm). Something like:

```
SELECT
  field1
  field2
  ...
FROM DE1
  INNER JOIN DE2
    DE1.PrimaryKey on DE2.PrimaryKey
```

Or use a third party tool like [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-6) if you don't like writing SQL.

Let me know if this helps! :-)